# How to calculate consecutive events?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Given the following JSON object with the person's stay days in hotel per months:

```
[{u'month': u'7', u'stay_days': {u'value': 1.0}},
 {u'month': u'8', u'stay_days': {u'value': 1.0}},
 {u'month': u'9', u'stay_days': {u'value': 1.0}}]
```

I should check if the person visited the hotel at least one time per month during 2 consecutive months in the last 3 months.

I get stuck with checking consecutive visits.

```
arr = '''[ {
            "stay_days": {
                "value": 1.0
            }, 
            "month": "1"
        }, 
        {
            "stay_days": {
                "value": 1.0
            }, 
            "month": "2"
        }, 
        {
            "stay_days": {
                "value": 1.0
            }, 
            "month": "3"
        }]'''
json_object = json.loads(arr)
dt = datetime.strptime(datetime.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%f'), "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%f")
month = dt.month
months = []
for line in json_object:
    months.append(line["key"])
months

if (int(month) - int(max(months))) > 0 and (int(month) - int(max(months))) <= 3:  
    for line in json_object:
        # ???
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather than using datetime to get the current month you can get it easier using time:

```
current_month = int(time.strftime('%m'))
```

Rather than just putting the whole json object into a list, you can filter out any data from months more than 3 months ago and also filter out any months without any stay days:

```
months = []
for line in json_object:
    if current_month - int(line['month']) < 3 and line['stay_days']['value'] > 0:
        months.append(int(line['month']))
```

If we sort the months (reverse sort used to bring most recent to the top) and iterate through them, if there are any two adjacent months, then the person visited the hotel in 2 consecutive months in the last 3.

```
months.sort(reverse=True)
consecutive_months = False
print(months)
for i in range(len(months) - 1):
    if months[i] - months[i+1] == 1:
        consecutive_months = True
        break

if consecutive_months:
    print('Visited hotel during 2 consecutive months out of the last 3')
```